# Can't get $_COOKIE[''] inside PHP function

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have a custom WordPress plugin that I developed.

Inside it I have 2 functions:

```
<?php
function A (){
   B ();
}

function B (){
   $result = "XXX" . $_COOKIE['mtc_id'] . "XXX";
   return $result;
}

echo $_COOKIE['mtc_id'];
?>
```

Why is my `$_COOKIE['mtc_id']` null in `function B ()` ($result = "XXXXXX") whereas when I echo `$_COOKIE['mtc_id']` I get my desired cookie value?

I'm sure it's something very basic but I am missing it. I even tried to define it outside and use the variable inside the function but still in vain.

Of course, my cookie is of same domain and as mentioned, if I echo it, it gives me the required string.

Also, the cookie is already set because `function A ()` is trigered way after the cookie is loaded. I have simplified the code to the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

You did not return the value in your B function

```
<?php
        
        function A (){
           echo B ();
        }
        
        function B (){
           $result = "XXX" . $_COOKIE['mtc_id'] . "XXX";
           //Always remember to return the value;
           return $result;
        }
    
    echo $_COOKIE['mtc_id'];
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had returned it. It was still empty. I'll update the above question.

Comment: When you return it you still need to echo it in the A function or did you assign it to a variable and you are getting null?